# How to send keystrokes as the last value using xdotool?

Tags: linux, lazarus, keystroke, xdotool, active-window

After searching online and on stackoverflow, I finally figured out how to inject keystrokes into an active window using the following command.
`xdotool windowactivate --sync <window> key <keystroke>`
This works as expected. However, every keystroke is injected in the front of the characters already in the box or as the first characters. I want to always inject new characters at the end of whatever is already there in the box. Does anyone know how to do this with xdotool command. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

xdotool allows you to send multiple keys, one after another, so :

`xdotool windowactivate --sync <window> key End <keystroke>`